# Is it possible to usi cgi (python/perl etc) on the server side of a Progressive Web App?

Tags: cgi, progressive-web-apps

The question is quite explanatory and I do not think I need to add more ... if not: how?

To be more verbose: my web app is running on a server, onto which I need to access system functions (disks, RTC, folders, etc). Can I use PWA in this case and how?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be useful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html

Comment: Oh yes, I know that. Sorry maybe my question was misleading. Can I use CGI techniques on a PWA application?

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this question that make it too broad. 1) PWA means a lot of things to a lot of people. Please be more specific. 2) Which CGI techniques? You list several. I could answer "Yes" and it would be correct but I can't write code to answer this without more info.

Comment: Yes, sorry and thank you for your time. I am starting studying Google PWA, following their tutorials and I would like to migrate a web app of mine to PWA to let me handle it through my smartphone. The web app has many calls to python CGI scripts to handle some server specific system. Is this straighforward for PWA (as for any web app) or not?

Comment: Yes, it is straightforward